# Use of SELECT with OFFSET

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
select FIELD
from TABLE
order by FIELD
LIMIT 1
OFFSET (select ceil(count(*)/2) from TABLE);
```

I'm getting an error in it. **Is it possible to use 2nd select statement in this way as it will be returning just a number.** If not, Why?

Comment: You can't use SELECT here because it is a SYNTAX validation issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, same select statement can be used with `where` or `having`

Comment: I have posted an answer below, you may check out.

Comment: i don't think this is possible.. get your offset via code and pass it into your query.

Comment: it's possible with dynamic MySQL @itdoesntwork i've posted a answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go dynamic MySQL with this one.

```
SET @OFFSET = "( SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / 2) FROM test )";

SET @SQL = "
 SELECT 
  a
 FROM 
  test
 ORDER BY a
 LIMIT 1
 OFFSET ?
";

PREPARE dynamic FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE dynamic USING @OFFSET;
```

Comment: Its not giving any error but offset doesn't work, as it's giving only the first field value. You can try adding multiple rows in the table, each time it returns the first row item independent of offset

Comment: "SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / 2) FROM test"; should be  (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / 2) FROM test);

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon.. i've eddited mine answer.